# Liferay 7.0 redirect to another jsp page with js click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, liferay-7

I have two jsp, view1 jsp, and view2.jsp. I have a button in view1 jsp and I want that button to redirect me to view2.jsp. I'm following the tutorials in liferay and I just want to know how will I able to do that using click function in jquery

Render Command:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {\
       "javax.portlet.name=" + HelloWorldPortletKeys.HELLO_WORLD,
       "mvc.command.name=/jsp/view2"
    },
    service = MVCRenderCommand.class
)
public class EditEntryMVCRenderCommand implements MVCRenderCommand {
@Override
public String render(
    RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) {

    return "/jsp/view2.jsp";
}
}
```

view2.jsp

```
<portlet:renderURL var="view2URL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcRenderCommandName" value="/jsp/view2" />
    <portlet:param name="entryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(entry.getEntryId()) %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

JS click function

```
$("#buttonid").click(function() {
    $("#div1").load("${view2URL}");

)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  Ajax you can achieve this kind of requirement.
In `serveresource` method add the following line

```
include("/jsp/loadResult.jsp", resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
```